# Why does CMake not include Fortran module files of a third party Fortran library?

Tags: cmake, fortran, static-libraries

I am trying to compile a single Fortran source file `main.f90` with cmake that includes a single external Fortran library:

```
USE RAD_Module
```

The project compiles fine with the following simple, handwritten makefile:

```
all:
    gfortran -c -I/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/include main.f90
    gfortran -L/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/lib -lRAD -o test.out main.o
```

The external static library does not have a `CMakeLists.txt` and its structure looks like this:

- Its `*.mod` module files are located in `/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/include/`.
- Its `librad.a` file is located in `/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/lib/`.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)
project("myProject" Fortran)
enable_language(Fortran)

## Target from sources:
add_executable(myProject main.f90)

## Link library:
link_directories("/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/lib")
link_directories("/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/include")

find_library(RAD
             NAMES librad.a 
             HINTS "/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/lib")

if(NOT RAD)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "RAD library not found!")
endif()

target_link_libraries(myProject RAD)
```

With this `CMakeLists.txt` cmake successfully produces a makefile. However, when I subsequently try to `make` the code, I get the following error message:

```sh
   15 |   USE RAD_Module
      |      1
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'rad_module.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The file `rad_module.mod` is located in the folder `/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/include`.

Comment: `include_directories(/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/include)` will enable the lookup for the `.mod` file. The Makefile stops at "building" (so need include/mod files), this should solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Pierre de Buyl pointed me to the solution. In order to include the `*.mod` files, I had to add the line:

```
target_include_directories(myProject PUBLIC "/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/include")
```

after calling `add_executable()`. 
Furthermore I had to link the path `${RAD}` itself, instead of the object `RAD` in the following call:

```
target_link_libraries(myProject ${RAD})
```

This successfully links the library.
Lastly, linking the library directories with `link_directories()` had no impact and I removed the corresponding lines entirely.
The working `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)
project("myProject" Fortran)
enable_language(Fortran)

## Target from sources:
add_executable(myProject main.f90)

## Link library:
find_library(RAD
             NAMES librad.a 
             HINTS "/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/lib")

if(NOT RAD)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "RAD library not found!")
endif()

target_include_directories(myProject PUBLIC "/usr/local/rad_v2.0.0/include")

target_link_libraries(myProject ${RAD})
```